# How do I compile a C program with SDL2_TTF on Windows 11?

Tags: c, windows, sdl-2

I have a C project, with multiple files and headers, that all use SDL2. I am using Windows 11, so I compile all the files like this, with mingw64 installed:

```
set CFLAGS=-IC:/path/to/SDL2/include -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -LC:/path/to/SDL2/lib
gcc src/*.c %CFLAGS% -mwindows -o build/main
```

In my project, I would like to display text with SDL2_ttf, so how would I compile my project to include that?

A thing to note are that the entire folder of SDL2 is located in my project directory, and I have simply put the `SDL2.dll` file in the `build` folder, so that the output file will run.

Comment: Simply adding `-lSDL2_ttf` at the end of the command should work. You also need to download SDL2_ttf and add it to `-I` and `-L` like you did with SDL.

Comment: how specifically can I add an extra file folder to `-I` and `-L`?

Comment: You write it twice. `-IC:/path/to/SDL2/include -IC:/path/to/SDL2_ttf/include`, and similarly for `-L`.